# Store mysql variable in a group by and use in statement to prevent duplicate calculation

Tags: mysql, variables, optimization

Given an example query like

```
SELECT IF(
        ABS(sum(grades) / count(*) * 100) < 1,
        ROUND(sum(grades) / count(*) * 100, 2),
        IF(ABS(sum(grades) / count(*) * 100) < 10,
            ROUND(sum(grades) / count(*) * 100, 1),
            ROUND(sum(grades) / count(*) * 100, 0)
        )
)
from important_table
group by timestamp
```

is it possible to not have to calculate the sum 3 times every grouping, but instead store the `sum(grades) / count(*) * 100` in a variable beforehand, still grouped by timestamp, and use that in the query? This looks a bit dirty and repeating to me.

Is that a real optimization possibility? Or does mysql cache it anyway when executing the query?

Comment: Never use `count(*)`, use `count(1)` instead. It is much faster.
Also, take a look at mysql `AVG` function

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about recalculating the values.  The SQL optimizer can decide to calculate them only once if it wants (althoughI don't think the MySQL optimizer does this).

However, assuming that `grades` is not `NULL`, you can simplify your expressions by using `avg()`:

```
select (case when ABS(avg(grades) * 100) < 1
             then ROUND(avg(grades) * 100, 2)
             when ABS(avg(grades) * 100) < 10
             then ROUND(avg(grades) * 100, 1)
             else ROUND(avg(grades) * 100, 0)
        end)
from important_table
group by timestamp;
```